# how to update subversion (svn) from source when previously installed from yum

Tags: linux, svn, centos, yum

I've installed svn 1.8.0 from source using makefile and then remove svn 1.6.3 with yum.

What I did:

```
downloaded and untar svn1.8.0
./configure
make
make install
yum remove subversion
httpd restart
svn --version
```

Everything went fine, but when I do svn --version, it is version 1.6.3

It there a way to replace the old svn version installed from yum?

I'm using centos 5.9 with cpanel installed.

**Update**

I just saw I have 2 version installed. One in /usr/local/bin and one in /usr/bin. How can I change the default one?

Answer (score 0):

Use "rpm -e subversion" or "rpm -e svn". This will remove the installed rpm version of svn. And then install svn from source.

Comment: I have both svn version but it is not using the good one by default. How to change that?

Comment: Was it removed properly? You can also try using software center to removed the rpm version. If removed, then /usr/bin/svn should be removed (this was install via yum) and /usr/local/bin/svn was installed from source. Above command should remove the rpm version. You might try using "/usr/local/bin/svn" explicitly calling the one you need.